# Dialogflow Fulfillment - Create a New Row in a Google Spreedsheet (Using Sheetdb io) - Here is the Code

Tags: json, google-sheets, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm trying to get my Dialogflow agent to create a new row with their contact information in a Google Sheet. I'm using Sheetdb.io to use the sheet as an API.

I have it so that it pulls information from the Google Spreadsheet, but I haven't been able to get it to create a new row.

Below is my code that I have right now. (I followed along a tutorial on YouTube by Axel Web Technologies)

```
function createHybridDataHandler(agent){
const{
    Email, FirstName, LastName
} = agent.parameters;

const data = [{
    Email: Email, 
    FirstName: FirstName, 
    LastName: LastName,
    Workout: Email,
    thefirstname: FirstName,
    thelastname: LastName
}];
axios.post('https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/hsb5ovk40x88i', data);
agent.add(`Done`);
```

}

This is the code I have for the intentMap.

```
intentMap.set ('CreateHybridData', createHybridDataHandler);
```

I have axios set up in both the index and package in Dialogflow. (Used axios to pull data from the Google Spreadsheet successfully)

Edit: Sorry I forgot to provide the errors I'm getting. Below you'll find the errors I'm encountering in Firebase when checking the logs.

```
dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
Function execution started

> dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Initializing firebase-admin may fail


> dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
Dialogflow Request headers: {"host":"us-central1-archie-personal-trainer-pueafg.cloudfunctions.net","user-agent":"Google-Dialogflow","transfer-encoding":"chunked","accept":"*/*","accept-encoding":"gzip,deflate,br","content-type":"application/json","forwarded":"for=\"66.249.84.223\";proto=https","function-execution-id":"e3y2hwjsi092","x-appengine-country":"ZZ","x-appengine-default-version-hostname":"b6b956e25660d8640p-tp.appspot.com","x-appengine-https":"on","x-appengine-request-log-id":"5ee6818900ff04307a9500ff68ef0001737e6236623935366532353636306438363430702d7470000139303866373866633530636138623435363966303164656633393333393136383a3334000100","x-appengine-user-ip":"66.249.84.223","x-cloud-trace-context":"47d4c8b63058cf02e15d32b293b42f1a/16021772533127728568;o=1","x-forwarded-for":"66.249.84.223","x-forwarded-proto":"https","connection":"close"}
```

> 

```
dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
Dialogflow Request body: {"responseId":"e5435eeb-249b-4f78-9a5a-0cd51b312807-2db64ae0","queryResult":{"queryText":"Jordan","parameters":{"Email":"cjgibson440@gmail.com","FirstName":"Michael","LastName":"Jordan"},"allRequiredParamsPresent":true,"outputContexts":[{"name":"projects/archie-personal-trainer-pueafg/agent/sessions/7f183f01-5ae4-830d-5db9-07d689eb2d02/contexts/__system_counters__","parameters":{"no-input":0,"no-match":0,"Email":"cjgibson440@gmail.com","Email.original":"cjgibson440@gmail.com","FirstName":"Michael","FirstName.original":"Michael","LastName":"Jordan","LastName.original":"Jordan"}}],"intent":{"name":"projects/archie-personal-trainer-pueafg/agent/intents/74086fa6-8d30-48a8-a439-397094c4ab7e","displayName":"CreateHybridData"},"intentDetectionConfidence":1,"languageCode":"en"},"originalDetectIntentRequest":{"payload":{}},"session":"projects/archie-personal-trainer-pueafg/agent/sessions/7f183f01-5ae4-830d-5db9-07d689eb2d02"}
```

> 

```
dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
Function execution took 2879 ms, finished with status code: 200
```

> 

```
dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
Unhandled rejection
```

> 

```
dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
Error: Request failed with status code 400 at createError (/srv/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15) at settle (/srv/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12) at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/srv/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11) at emitNone (events.js:111:20) at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7) at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12) at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would help if you updated your question to include any errors you got while running this, or any problems you encountered. If it isn't working, what *is* it doing? The more information you provide, the better our chances are of helping you. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Prisoner Thanks for the help, I just added all of the logs that I see in Firebase when I try to run it. This is my first post on Stack Overflow so if there is anything I did wrong I'll try and fix it ASAP. I appreciate you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important bit in your error is the line

> Request failed with status code 400

The [Sheets DB status code documentation](https://docs.sheetdb.io/#http-status-codes) says that error code 400 indicates "API could not understand the request", which suggests that your data is formatted incorrectly.

The [POST - create row](https://docs.sheetdb.io/#post-create-row) API endpoint says that it is expecting a POST body with a JSON object containing a "data" field with an array of objects. Although you are sending an array of objects, these aren't part of an object with a data field.

Your code should probably look something more like:

```
const data = [{
    Email: Email, 
    FirstName: FirstName, 
    LastName: LastName,
    Workout: Email,
    thefirstname: FirstName,
    thelastname: LastName
}];
const body = {
  data
};
axios.post('https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/hsb5ovk40x88i', body);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked! I really appreciate your answer. This was a huge help! :)